# Rails fields_for produces a broken <label for=""> value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine

The code illustrating the bug is from a Redmine plugin. A `_form.html.erb` partial contains this `fields_for`:

```
<%= f.fields_for :information do |information| %>
  <p><%= information.text_field :middlename, :label => l(:label_people_middlename) %></p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :lastname, :required => true %></p>
```

Then one of the fields declares a label:

```
<p><%= information.select :gender, Person.get_genders, :label => l(:label_people_gender)%></p>
```

That generates this HTML:

```
<p><label for="person[information_attributes]_gender">Gender</label>
  <select name="person[information_attributes][gender]" id="person_information_attributes_gender">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">Male</option>
  <option value="1">Female</option>
</select></p>
```

The `<label for="">` value has `[]` in it instead of underscores `_`, so it does not match the target field's `id="person_information_attributes_gender"`. Clicking on the label does not put the keyboard focus into that `<select>` field.

Is this a known bug in Rails 4.2.8? Is there a fix or workaround available - besides just writing the `<label>` in raw HTML?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try using an actual Rails label, instead of passing label as an option to the 'select'? (I'll be honest, I haven't actually seen the `label` option on a select like that, before). Something like this:

```
<p>
  <%= information.label :gender, l(:label_people_gender) %>
  <%= information.select :gender, Person.get_genders %>
</p>
```

Comment: Then I get two labels. One is correct:  `<label for="person_information_attributes_gender">Gender</label> <label for="person[information_attributes]_gender">translation missing: en.field_gender</label>`

Comment: Erm... You mentioned this is from a redmine plugin? Is the plugin adding that extra label parameter or... something?? I've really never seen that before. Is it using a custom form builder?  (Is there a `builder: ` option defined in the `form_for` tag in the view, or does RedMine otherwise define it's own form builder?).  Where is that label parameter coming from!  Edit to add: Can you link the redmine plugin in question? Is your repo/code in a public github?

Comment: The plugin is `redmine_people`, and I can't find a `def select` in any of our (many) plugins. The `form_for` has no `builder:` on it. My editor can't figure out where the `.select` is coming from, so I will now have to go spelunking manually in the rails gem sources...

Comment: Well `select` is a rails method, but *something* has to be adding that `label` option to it. My first guess would be a custom `FormBuilder`...

Comment: Yup it's Redmine's bug:  `./lib/redmine/views/labelled_form_builder.rb:class Redmine::Views::LabelledFormBuilder`. I haven't read the code yet but I will guess that it adds the label option...